# Does the DNS lookup result mean that my nameserver is pointed nowhere?

Tags: dns, nameserver

I changed my domain's nameservers, but I don't think the change was processed correctly. Can anyone help me understand the result below "AFTER"? In my registrant's control panel, I change the name servers from `ns1.secure.net` (etc.) to `ns1.linode.com` (etc.). But, after the changed, it looked like the DNS was pointed nowhere at all.

*Is this a normal in-between state during the process of nameserver changeover, or does this mean that the new nameservers were not correctly assigned?*

**BEFORE:**

```
$dig mobtownballroom.com

; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> mobtownballroom.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 19515
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 2, ADDITIONAL: 2

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;mobtownballroom.com.    IN A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
mobtownballroom.com.    69141   IN  A   66.228.58.195

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
mobtownballroom.com.    69141   IN  NS  ns2.secure.net.
mobtownballroom.com.    69141   IN  NS  ns1.secure.net.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
ns1.secure.net.  63323  IN  A   192.220.124.10
ns2.secure.net.  63323  IN  A   192.220.125.10

;; Query time: 44 msec
;; SERVER: 128.220.143.30#53(128.220.143.30)
;; WHEN: Fri Apr 4 18:19:12 2014
;; MSG SIZE rcvd: 131
```

**AFTER:**

```
$dig mobtownballroom.com

; <<>> DiG 9.2.4 <<>> -t ANY mobtownballroom.com
;; global options: printcmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 10778
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;mobtownballroom.com.    IN ANY

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
com.     900    IN  SOA a.gtld-servers.net. nstld.verisign-grs.com. 1396650155 1800 900 604800 86400

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 64.22.68.60#53(64.22.68.60)
;; WHEN: Fri Apr 4 18:22:57 2014
;; MSG SIZE rcvd: 110
```

(For the time being, I have changed the nameservers back to `ns1.secure.net`, so if you run `dig` yourself now, you'll see "BEFORE".)

More detail about how I got here:

- A previous developer registered the domain with MelbourneIT.
- I transferred the registration to active-domain. The DNS settings carried over.
- Having trouble getting the `www` subdomain to work with the nameservrs, I tried to point the nameservers to Linode.
- The site "went down" and, as you can see, the DNS pointed nowhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you did not get an answer because the DNS server your client computer is pointed to is not the authority. The *require authority* flag (if I remember the name right) is likely set and the request not completed because the DNS you queried was not the authority. This can be common if you are pointed to a Bind instance. By default, *recursive look-up* is not set and/or try a *query directly* is not set in Bind. I went through this recently, but forgive me if the exact setting names and flag names are not exactly right because I am going off of my memory.

Try: dig @ns1.linode.com mobtownballroom.com any

Alternatively, try: dig +trace mobtownballroom.com any

These should give you an answer. The first one you are querying the authoritative name server directly. If this does not work, the next will do a trace and find the authority.

Comment: OK, this helps. I'm not sure I have enough access through the dinky "control panel" offered by my domain registrant to follow your advice, but I will see if they can help me given this information. Thanks.

Comment: Dig is available via Linux of course. But it can be available on Windows too. I have not done this. I use Linux. However, here is a link that may help: http://nil.uniza.sk/windows/windows-7/how-install-dig-dns-tool-windows-7

Comment: I'm on Linux; dig is fine. I meant the tools to change the "require authority" flag or whatever its proper name is.

Comment: For the two commands I gave, you will not need that. The require authority comes from Dig. The other two are settings in Bind itself.

Comment: In fact, while I was thinking about it, I was not suggesting changing any settings. I was just explaining what I found and how to get around it. If you can change the settings, then that would help for the future.

Comment: OK, I see. You explained how to get more information. But why changing name servers seems to fail is still unknown.

Comment: When you use Dig, it sets the require authority bit in the request packet. If you use Dig against any DNS that is not the authority, the results will be the same- short of info. But if you specify the authority using @dns-server, then it should work. I use my local DNS for DNS stability testing. I set those two settings I mentioned and it retrieves directly from the authority for me which is the same as the +trace in the second command automatically if my DNS or my forwarders are not the authority.